# JSONP Convert to Array Locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data that is being returned from a remote server.  However the problem that I'm running into is sometimes "thing" will be an array of "things" or just a single "thing"

"thing" has a name and value property, along with a couple of others.

The problem I'm having is when just a single "thing" is returned.  Right now I have code that looks like this.  There has to be a better way.

```
var array = [];
if (data.results.thing.length > 1) {

var array = $.map(data.results.thing, function (item) {

    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.value
    }
});
}
else {

array = $.makeArray({
    label: data.results.thing.name,
    value: data.results.thing.value
});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, jQuery is smarter than that; [$.makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) will return a true array as is, or make the object into an array as needed:

```
var array = $.map( $.makeArray(data.results.thing), function (item) {

    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.value
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/):

```
var thing = data.results.thing;
if (! $.isArray(thing))
    thing = [ thing ]; // array literal containing one item: thing
var array = $.map(thing, function (item) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.value
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isArray` method to determine if a value is an array, and you can make it one if it isn't:

```
var arr = data.results.thing;

if (!$.isArray(arr)) {
  arr = [arr];
}
```

Now it's always an array, so you can treat it the same way all the time.